# How to select all file in Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I had create a button and I had written following code in it

```
declare
     l_flname varchar2(500) ;
begin
    l_flname := GET_FILE_NAME( File_Filter=> 'All Files (*.*)|*.*|',message=> 'select file to load');
    if l_flname is not null
    then
     :load.FILE_NAM := l_flname;
    else
         message('Please Select File To Load',acknowledge);
         message('Please Select File To Load',no_acknowledge);
         synchronize;
         raise form_trigger_failure;
    end if;
end;
```

But when I run form and click on the button  Than I should open a Windows and from there I can select a file but instead of that I get message 'select file to load'
Please help me out

Comment: Which version of Forms are you using?

Comment: i am using oracle oracle forms 10g

Comment: That's a web-based version.  You are aware of the implications of that, in terms of which directories (and hence which files) you'll be looking at?  That is, GET_FILE_NAME will be searching the *app server* not your local PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webutil to do the same to load files from Client machine

Please find the links below which might be useful

http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/01/open-file-dailog-box-example-using.html

http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-1810290.html